# Put URL parameters in variables

Tags: php, variables, syntax

I have url with id number like this : http://google.org/something.php?id=12345

And `php` file :

```
<?php 
$noid= "0000000000000";    
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    if(!$id)
    {
        $id=$noid;
    }
?>

<?php echo $id ?>

<?php
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=<?php echo $id ?>';
var_dump($uri);
?>
```

All i need is put **12345** (*dynamic number*) in `$uri` but i don't know right syntax to do it.

Just tried something like :

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=$id';

$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=.$id.';
```

but not work. Please help.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has already been answered and is a very simple fix but that's it. Everyone is just giving you a fix without telling you what is wrong with your code. So here it goes

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=<?php echo $id ?>';
```

There are 2 problems with that.

1) You are already in PHP mode so you don't need to start and end PHP tags again.

2) Variables are not interpolated in single quotes, so use double quotes.

```
$uri = "http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=$id"; // right
```

Also you mentioned this following version does not work either

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=$id';
```

Because it incorporates point 1 mentioned above but not point 2.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id='.$id;
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=<?php echo $id ?>';
```

To

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id='.$id;
```

> OR

Add double `"` at start and end.

```
$uri = "http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=$id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about how quotes work within PHP [Single Quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and [Double Quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Over here you need to simply change your quotes around the strings as

```
$uri = "http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id=$id";
       ^^                                                    ^^
```

and for this it should be

```
$uri = 'http://nooooo.com/another.php?match_timestamp=0&id='.$id;
                                                           ^^^
```

and Yes there are many other ways to do this task also ..